# How to rerender Chart.js properly in Vue3 component

Tags: vue.js, performance, charts, vuejs3, chart.js

I am creating a quick chart to compare momentum movement on 6-7 currency pairs: bitcoin, ether, tron, etc. I receive ticks over websocket every 500ms. I am using **Vue3** library, **Centrifuge** for websockets and **Chart.js** for charts. After 10 seconds I start facing huge performance issues. I think that the problem is how I render the Vue component because I pass tick data in a component property and use a watcher inside the Chart component. I would appreciate any advice.

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div id="chart">
      <Chart :ticks="ticks"/>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <Button label="Start" color="start" @click="start"></Button>
      <Button label="Stop" color="stop" @click="stop"></Button>
      <Button label="Clear" color="clear" @click="clear"></Button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>Remaining seconds: {{ counter }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { Centrifuge } from "centrifuge";
import Chart from "./components/Chart.vue";
import Button from "./components/Button.vue";

const ticks = ref({});
let counter = ref(30);
let interval = ref(null)
const symbols = ["btcusdt", "ethusdt", "solusdt", "adausdt", "avaxusdt", "dogeusdt"];
const subscriptions = [];
const MAX_LENGTH = 300;
let centrifuge = null;

async function getCentrifugeToken() {
  return "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmZWVkZXIifQ.Ay6h5gvwuuEedjneBaRi8aL0lolrB9GJaktFj7GUz78";
}

onMounted(() => {

  centrifuge = new Centrifuge("ws://localhost:8001/connection/websocket", {
    token: null,
    getToken: getCentrifugeToken,
    maxServerPingDelay: 5000
  });

  // Subscribe and send tick over props to Chart component
  symbols.forEach(symbol => {
    subscriptions.push(centrifuge.newSubscription(symbol));
    ticks.value[symbol] = [];
  });
  subscriptions.forEach((sub) => {
    sub.on('publication', function(message) {
      const tickData = JSON.parse(message.data);

      // Remove first element if array length is greater than MAX_LENGTH
      if (ticks.value[tickData.symbol].length > MAX_LENGTH) {
        ticks.value[tickData.symbol].shift();
      }

      // Push new tick to array
      const length = ticks.value[tickData.symbol].push({
          x: new Date().getTime(),
          y: tickData.price,
      });
      ticks.value[tickData.symbol][length -1]["percent"] = parseFloat(((tickData.price / ticks.value[tickData.symbol][0].y - 1) * 100).toFixed(4));
    });
    sub.subscribe();
  });
  
});


function start() {
  console.log("Start");
  centrifuge.connect();

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    counter.value--;
    if (counter.value === 0) {
      stop();
    }
  }, 1000);

}

function stop() {
  centrifuge.disconnect();
  clearInterval(interval.value);
}

function clear() {
  clearInterval(interval.value);
  Object.keys(ticks.value).forEach((symbol) => {
    ticks.value[symbol] = [];
  });
}
  
</script>

<style>

#app {
  display: block;
}

#chart,
#buttons {
  display: block;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
</style>
```

**Chart.vue**

```js
<template>
  <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</template>

<script setup>
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto';
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { onMounted, watch } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['ticks']);
let chart;

onMounted(() => {
  const el = document.getElementById("line-chart");
  chart = new Chart(el, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: [], // Time labels will go here
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'BTCUSD',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: '#fc9d03',
            borderColor: '#fc9d03',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'ETHUSD',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: '#4e03fc',
            borderColor: '#4e03fc',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'SOLUSD',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: '#ce03fc',
            borderColor: '#ce03fc',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'ADAUSD',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: '#a3d1d1',
            borderColor: '#a3d1d1',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'AVAXUSD',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: '#fc0314',
            borderColor: '#fc0314',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'DOGEUSD',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: '#f5cf47',
            borderColor: '#f5cf47',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        animations: false,
        layout: {
          padding: {
            right: 50
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            anchor: "top",
            align: "right",
            offset: -35,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 10,
            color: "#fff",
            backgroundColor: (context) => {
              return context.dataset.backgroundColor.toString();
            },
            padding: {
              top: 5,
              bottom: 5,
              right: 5,
              left: 5,
            },
            display: (context) => {
              return context.dataIndex === context.dataset.data.length - 1;
            },
            formatter: (value, context) => {
              return context.dataset.label;
            },
          },
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                display: false,
                time: {
                    unit: 'millisecond'
                }
            }
        }
    }
  });
});

watch(props.ticks, (newTicks) => {
  Object.keys(newTicks).forEach((symbol, index) => {
    let rawTicks = newTicks[symbol].map(tick => (
      {
        x: tick.x,
        y: tick.percent
      }
    ));
    chart.data.datasets[index].data = rawTicks;
  });
  chart.update('quiet');
});

</script>

<style scoped>
#line-chart {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Should be `watch(() => props.ticks`. `watch(props.ticks` is undocumented afaik and supposedly sets a deep watcher, this is the reason it works but also can cause bugs and overhead, probably the problem here. Create new ticks object and assign it once with `ticks.value = ...` in a parent to avoid multiple change detection triggers. Try to add debounce to a watcher if the performance is still subpar

Comment: Not an important source of overhead (since animation is disabled), but there's no `quiet` transition in chart.js (nor a user-defined one, apparently); you probably wanted to use `chart.update("none")`, see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.4.1/developers/api.html#update-mode)